# Generate vCard from Contact Data by java

Tags: java

I would like to be able to generate a **vCard** given the data contained within person_contact.

Here is my code.But I am unable to generate the vcard properly.

```
private void m1() throws IOException {
        Contact contact = buildContact();

        File f = new File("contact.vcf");
        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f);
        String outputImageFilePath = "contact.vcf";
        createDirectoryIfNotExists(outputImageFilePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            String str = "BEGIN:VCARD\n" + "VERSION:4.0\n" + "N:" + contact.getFull_name() + ";;;\n"
                    + "FN:" + contact.getFull_name() + "\n" + "ORG:" + contact.getOrganization_name()
                    + "\n" + "TITLE:" + contact.getTitle() + "\n" + "TEL;TYPE="
                    + contact.getPhone_2_type() + ";VALUE=uri:" + contact.getPhone_2() + "\n"
                    + "TEL;TYPE=" + contact.getPhone_3_type() + ",voice;VALUE=uri:tel:"
                    + contact.getPhone_3() + "\n" + "EMAIL:" + contact.getEmail() + "\n" + "FAX:"
                    + contact.getFax() + "\n" + "STREET1:" + contact.getStreet1() + "\n" + "STREET2:"
                    + contact.getStreet2() + "\n" + "CITY:" + contact.getCity() + "\n" + "STATE:"
                    + contact.getState() + "\n"

                    + "END:VCARD";

            fop.write(str.getBytes());
            // Now read the content of the vCard after writing data into it
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contact.vcf"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            // close the output stream and buffer reader
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
            System.out.println("The data has been written");
        }

        else
            System.out.println("This file does not exist");

    }

    private static Contact buildContact() {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setCity("xxxxxx");
        contact.setCountry("xxxxxx");
        contact.setEmail("test@xxxxxx.com");
        contact.setFax("123456789");
        contact.setFull_name("Dummy Name");
        contact.setOrganization_name("Dummy-technologies");
        contact.setPhone("123456789");
        contact.setPhone_type("work");
        contact.setPhone_2("987456321");
        contact.setPhone_2_type("home");
        contact.setPhone_3("564789451236");
        contact.setPhone_3_type("work2");
        contact.setPostal_code("500000");
        contact.setState("state");
        contact.setStreet1("street1");
        contact.setStreet2("stree2");
        contact.setTitle("company");
        contact.setWebsite_url("www.text.com");
        return contact;

    }
```

It is not generating the vcard properly.Can any one help me plz.

Comment: What do you mean by "not generating the vcard properly"? What is the problem? Are some values wrong? Is there an exception?

Comment: no exception.some fields are generating some are not.

Comment: I am unable to upload the generated file here.

Comment: Which fields are not being generated? Because I just tested it myself and could not find any problems. My generated file looks exactly like I would expect it to. Can you post the code of your Contact class and the content of your generated file? (Just insert both and put each into a code block)